# Finite-Dimensional Homogeneous Contractible Spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples, geometric-topology, continuum-theory

Suppose that $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact, homogeneous and contractible (and thus connected).  Does $X$ have to be a point?

I couldn't think of a non-trivial example, and there isn't a counterexample in the plane.  The homogeneous planar continua have been classified (point, circle, pseudo-arc, circle of pseudo-arcs) and the only contractible one is a point.  Maybe there is some twisty sort of example in three or four dimensions, though?

Does it become true if $\dim(X) = n $ and is embeddable in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$?

By *homogeneous* I mean for any $x, y \in X$ there is a homeomorphism $f$ of $X$ with $f(x) = y$.  By *contractible* I mean the identity map on $X$ is homotopic to a constant map.  For example the circle is homogeneous but not contractible, and the closed disc is contractible but not homogeneous.

Comment: What's the definition of *homogeneous*?

Comment: @guidoar $\mathrm{Homeo}(X)$ acts transitively on $X$. In other words for all $x,y\in X$ there is an homeomorphism $f\colon X\to X$ with $f(x)=y$.

Comment: Ah, right. Thanks :)

Comment: An easy observation: there are such continua in $\Bbb R^\Bbb N$, for example $[0,1]^\Bbb N$. (Also "connected" is redundant in your list of properties, being implied by "contractible")

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti $[0,1]^N$ is not homogeneous. No homeomorphism maps a boundary point to an interior point.

Comment: Suppose that $X$ is a contractible CW complex. If $\dim X = 1$, then $X$ is a tree. Serre proves in *Trees* that any action of a finite group will have fixed points. That any finite $2$-dimension $G$-complex (with $G$ finite) admits fixed points is the Casacuberta-Dicks conjecture. They proved it originally for $X$ acyclic and $G$ solvable. So even though this is not exactly what you asked for, the problem seems hard (maybe the fact that we can work with the whole group $\mathsf {Homeo}(X)$ makes things easier, I don't know).

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti You are right, I didn't properly see that you wrote $\mathbb N$; I read $N$.

Comment: Ok, I added the relevant definitions and removed the superfluity of "connected."  Is there a way to adjust Bing's "two drill bits" space, perhaps?  I forget the exact properties of that space.

Comment: Another easy observation: if $X$ contractible is relaxed to $\pi_n(X)=0$ for $n\geq 1$ then the pseudo-arc is a (connected) example

Comment: For those of you (like me) who where looking for an example which is a manifold, this is not possible: a compact simply-connected manifold is orientable so it has $\mathbb Z$ for top homology. Hence, by homogeneity, no neighborhood of any point is homeomorphic to a disk, thus the "local topology" of a possible counterexample must be pretty nasty.

Comment: Nice observation @AdamChalumeau

Comment: Fun fact: if $G$ is a compact topological group and $G$ is contractible, then $G$ is the trivial group. This rules out such objects from being counterexamples.

Comment: I also just realized that the homogeneous planar continua are known to be the point, the circle, the pseudo-arc and the circle of pseudo-arcs, so that case is actually known.  Going to edit the post.

Comment: What about $S^{\infty}$?

Comment: It's infinite-dimensional, right?

Comment: @JohnSamples yes : )